# How to sort by associated model within given value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord, associations

I have model Item and model Stats.

```
 Item
   has_many :stats

 Stat
   belongs_to :items
```

In the model (e.g. mysql table) Stat there is 3 fields: 
rating
skin_id
item_id

So for Stat, it could be, like:

```
@item.stats => Array of stats for records with item_id = 1, with a differer skin_id
```

I need to sort all items, for a given skin_id by 'rating'.

Something like:

```
@items = Item.all.order('stats[currtnt_skin.id] DESC') (of course it doesn't work)
```

In other words i need to sort within array of:

```
@stats = @items.stats[current_skin.id]
@items.order (... by @stats ...)
```

How it could be done?

Comment: Could you paste somewhere some records (items, stats) and the desired output ? The question is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly I'm presuming by `belongs_to :items` you mean `belongs_to :item` (singular) given the presence of the `item_id` foreign key.

Secondly, to solve your specific query you can use:

```
Stat.where(:skin_id => skin_id).joins(:item).order("items.rating DESC")
```

However, if `skin_id` refers to another model - i.e. `Stat belongs_to :skin` and `Skin has_many :stats` then it may make more sense to start from there:

```
skin = Skin.find(1)
stats = skin.stats.order("rating DESC").includes(:item)
```

To get the items then just loop through them:

```
stats = skin.stats.order("rating DESC").includes(:item)

stats.each do |stat|
   stat.item
end
```

F

Comment: Is it possible to make it from 'Item side', not from Stat?

Comment: Because in such case i have an array of Stats, but not Items

Comment: To get the item just use the .item method - I've updated the example. By using the includes(:item) method, Rails does an 'eager load' of all of the Items in one SQL query, so it's not much of a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

@items = Item.join(:stats).order('skin_id DESC')

I believe, though I might be mistaken that joining the table will do so on the association you've defined.

Comment: I'm not going to stake much on it, but I'm reasonably confident you need to use includes rather than joins - at least in recent rails versions.  Joins does lazy loading, and so I think this won't actually work

Comment: you might be right...I was under the impression that includes just pulls in the related associated objects but didn't necessarily do it in one query. I could be mistaken, of course. Being mistaken is one of my best skills.

Answer (score 0):

in rails 3 it will be something like:

Item.includes("stats").order("stats.skin_id desc")

Comment: No, because stats.skin_id will return an array of stats for item, because i have many stats for a single Item. I have to provide skin_id, to sort only by provided skin_id

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
Item.includes("stats").where('stats.skin_id = ?', 1).order("stats.rating desc")
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not correct. Yes, i'm selecting all Items with skin_id provided, but they ordered by all stats.rating i have. There should be something like Item.includes("stats").where('stats.skin_id = ?', 1).order("stats.rating[skin_id] desc")

Comment: I think the place where I get confused is that stats.rating[skin_id] is not sql syntax I'm familiar with. Clearly from my incorrect response below I don't understand your question entirely...sorry :(

Comment: I can't understand this question too. Obvious that this is very simple  problem, but condition is not clear.

Comment: Of course order("stats.rating[skin_id] desc") is just an example, but not SQL syntax. I'm trying to show that i need not all array of stats.rating, but, for example, it's first value. like: array_of_stats[0]